# Различие ссылок и указателей C++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, аргументы

Опишите, пожалуйста, чем 1 код отличается от 2. Не понимаю как работает с памятью второй и почему результат тот же. Я новичок, не бейте

```
void Foo (int *pa)
{
    (*pa)++;
}

void main()
{
    int a = 0;
    cout << a << endl; //выводится 0
    Foo(&a);
    cout << a << endl; //выводится 1
}
```

```
void Foo (int &a)
{
    a++;
}

void main()
{
    int a = 0;
    cout << a << endl; //выводится 0
    Foo(a);
    cout << a << endl; //выводится 1
}
```

Comment: Второй в принципе можно рассматривать как первый, просто когда вы передаете что-то по ссылке, то взятие адреса и разыменование происходит "за сценой", невидимо для вас..

Comment: Еще важный момент - в первом случае указатель может быть потенциально нулевым, а ссылка - нет. Кроме того, указателю можно присвоить указатель на другой объект, а ссылки не ребиндятся.

Comment: [Посмотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/349?lq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка работает так-же как неизменяемый указатель, но без звёздочек.

```
int a = 7 ;
int * const pa = & a;
int & la = a ;
int & la = * pa ; // эффект тот-же
```

**a** - это переменная целочисленного типа. *l-value*
**pa** - это переменная типа указателя. Указателю можно присвоить только адрес l-value объекта.
При добавлении звёздочки `*` указатель превращается в l-value объект.
**la** - это переменная типа ссылки. Она может указывать только на l-value объект.

```
a     += 1 ;
(*pa) += 1 ; //  ===  a += 1 ;
la    -= 1 ; //  ===  a -= 1 ;
```

При передачи аргументом в функцию происходит копирование.  Копирование ссылки происходит путём копирования указателя, а не значения.

```
void Foo (int a)  
void Foo (int *pa)  
void Foo (int & la)
```

**a** - это новая локальная переменная с копией числа.
**pa** - это новый локальный указатель *(объект куда он указывает остаётся нетронутым)*.
**la** - это новая локальная ссылка *(объект куда ссылка указывает остаётся нетронутым)*.

---

*Ссылки имеют ограничения в использовании по сравнении с указателем.*

Ссылка не обязана иметь место хранения. У ссылки нет адреса. Команда получения адреса возвращает адрес реального объекта.
На ссылку нельзя назначить ссылку. Ссылка не может ссылаться на ссылку.
На ссылку нельзя выделить память.
На массив ссылок нельзя выделить память.
Ссылки нельзя хранить в массиве.
*На ссылку как элемент структуры/класса можно.*

Comment: Внутренний зануда говорит, что выражения не бывают ссылками, поэтому оператор `*` не может ничего превращать в ссылку.

Comment: `* ptr` - это l-value. И тогда ссылку можно инициализировать этим? так что-ли? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Угу, да. Lvalue типа int.