# Отличие указателя от ссылки

Tags: c++, c

Блуждая по пространствам интернета, не смог найти нормального объяснения отличий &ссылок от *указателей.
Прошу разъяснения: Как, где и когда использовать их, как конкретно они выполняются и какую функцию выполняют с демонстрацией выполнения примеров, и без сленга.

*Не отвечайте пожалуйста в виде - *Ну ссылки ссылаются на переменную, а указатели указывают на переменную*, *первый запрос в гугле {link}*, либо ссылка на сторонний сайт - мне нужно именно разъяснение*

Comment: С технической точки зрения указатель и ссылка - одно и тоже. Отличие - ссылка не может ссылаться по адресу `nullptr`.

Comment: почитайте ответ [Различие ссылок и указателей C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1447220/288358) может поможет

Comment: Тогда уж сразу вот этим вопросом закрывать: [Чем отличаются ссылки от указателей в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/349/215103).

Comment: Все-таки не совсем понял(
Но пример от @HolyBlackCat не плох.
Краткий Итог: судя по всему, нет смысла использовать указатели. Судя по всему указатели пережиток прошлого, ведь в том-же php обходятся без этого

Comment: Написал длиннющий ответ по последней ссылке. Не знаю, кто все это будет читать...

Comment: *"нет смысла использовать указатели"* Неправильный вывод.

Comment: Касательно ответа от @HolyBlackCat. В Вашем ответе, Вы обсуждаете и сравниваете ссылки. Я же понимаю как работают ссылки, но не понимаю как работает система указателей.

 Либо я что-то не замечаю, ибо я закипел и не в лучшем состоянии

Comment: Тогда идите читайте про указатели. Не думаю, что можно нормально понять ссылки, не поняв сначала указатели.